# Is $\left[ 0,1 \right)$ a completely metrizable space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

The definition of completely metrizable space can refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_metrizable_space

As we know,with usual metric, $\left[ 0,1 \right]$ is a complete metric space. So $\left[ 0,1 \right]$ with usual topology is a completely metrizable space.

Just as Wikipedia said, $\left( 0,1 \right)$ is a completely metrizable space although its usual metric is not complete.

So, what about $\left[ 0,1 \right)$?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts about this?

Comment: Let $d(x,y) = |\tan(\pi x/2) - \tan(\pi y/2)|$...

Comment: It’s a basic result that a subspace of a complete metric space is complete if and only if it is closed, and completely metrizable if and only if it’s a $G_\delta$ set. $[0,1)$ is not closed in the complete space $\Bbb R$, so it’s not complete, but it is a $G_\delta$, so it’s completely metrizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible : Note that $[0,\infty)$ is complete with an induced metric from $\mathbb{R}$ So $[0,1)$ is complete

Comment: Thanks. What about $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @pchappy this too as $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$, which has a complete product metric.